# How to get released maven version in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, maven-release-plugin

There are 2 jobs on Jenkins: maven release job and another one. I need to bypass released version variable from release job to another one.

Is there any vаriable of release version (set before the release job), which the release was performed with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the Parameterized Trigger Plugin in to pass the variables from one job to another

See this:
[Jenkins - passing variables between jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704677/jenkins-passing-variables-between-jobs)

Comment: The plugin able to pass variables between simple builds (jobs), but not from release build (where "Perform Maven release" option is available). At least I didn't find any solution using it.