# How can I pass parameters from a job to the other job when both the jobs are building inside a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have 3 jobs building in pipeline job as below

```
node('master') {
    stage ('first')
    parallel firstBranch: {
    build 'job1'
    build 'job2'
    }
    stage ('second')
    build 'job3'
}
```

My job2 can take parameters and it should be passed from job1. How can I do that in pipeline?

I cannot use Parameterized Trigger Plugin as I don't want to trigger one job from another.

I want a way to pass the parameters from one job1 to job2 inside pipeline project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins - passing variables between jobs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704677/jenkins-passing-variables-between-jobs)

Comment: @Bachu What kind of parameters should be passed?

Comment: @CSchulz 
Any kind of parameters that can supported by Jenkins. Right now I want to pass string parameter.

Comment: @GeroldBroser
I cannot use Parameterized Trigger Plugin as I don't want to trigger one job from another. 

I want a way to pass the parameters from one job1 to job2 inside pipeline project.

Comment: Where does the paramater in job1 comes from? git commit, etc?

Comment: @CSchulz Those are normal Jenkins parameters defined inside job1.

Comment: So you mean normal job parameters?

Comment: yes. Job parameters.

Comment: Why not using the same job parameters giving to job1 also for job2?

Comment: There are more answers to the question I linked than just the accepted. See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20467879/1744774).

Comment: @GeroldBroser
It is explaining only for build flow. Not for pipeline