# How to set a variable inside Jenkins Shell Command

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins build job. It has section for shell command where I read "version" of the current application that i am building.
Now, i want to set the Jenkins custom variable "VERSION" with the "version"  in the same shell command section.
I need to pass this value as parameter to some other job being triggered after successful build of this job.

[image]

Now, I would pass the Jenkins variable VERSION to some other Job.

[image]

Please suggest how can I do this.

Comment: checkout this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704677/jenkins-passing-variables-between-jobs, looks like similar to your query check for 2nd and 4th solution, might help

Comment: my use case is to create a variable inside one and then pass it to another.
I am not able to create the custom variable in the batch command section that i can pass in the parameterized way to another.

Answer (score 3):

Use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to inject runtime variables into Jenkins build process so that you can use in other build steps or you can pass it on to other Job's as input parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked. Though, I posted the exact steps.

Answer (score 3):

I could get some clue from Suresh's answer. I did the following steps and it worked well.

Step 1: Install Plugin “EnvInject Plugin”.

[image]

Step 2: Set the custom env variable and store that in env.properties

[image]

Step 3: Add POST Build Action, “Trigger parameterized build on other projects”

[image]

Step 4: Add the variables that the Post Build Job is expecting:
        Here the BUILD_NUMBER and FILE_VERSION are two parameterized variables 
        that the next Job is expecting. FILE_VERSION is passed as parameters 
        from properties file which was stored in STEP 2.

[image]