# Jenkins build is not resolving dependency from JFrog artifactory

Tags: jenkins, build, dependencies

- I have built a Jenkins pipeline which builds a project.
- The project
  has a dependent jar which is available in a JFrog repository.
- I have 
  added the JFrog repository in the `<repositories></repositories>`
  tag. But the jenkins build is not resolving the dependency.
- Is there 
  anything else I should configure to use the JFrog artifactory to
  fetch the dependency ?

Comment: View this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704677/jenkins-passing-variables-between-jobs

Comment: when Jar is available in JFrog, I can assume, you added it's dependency in men/gradle not in the Jenkins pipeline, right ? in that case there can be only one problem, that place where your pipeline got executed (Jenkins master or slave) by some strange reason do not have access to JFrog repo at all