# How to pass variables from a build to another in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Due to infrastructure constraints, in my Jenkinsfile, I would like to store some variables from build #1 and be able to access them from build #2 and next ones.

I tried to set some env variables, but it seems they are not saved from a build to another.

Is there to acheive that from Jenkinsfile? Or maybe to write them to a text file?

Jenkins version: 2.111

Comment: View this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704677/jenkins-passing-variables-between-jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use this mecanism which fits my requirements and works like a charm, so far:

```
if (currentBuild.previousBuild != null) {
    env.MY_VAR = currentBuild.previousBuild.getBuildVariables().get('MY_VAR ')
    echo "Old branch context restored"
} else {
    env.MY_VAR = createSomethingAtFirstBuild()
    echo "New branch context created"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write them to a text file, and store that as a build artifact in build#1.

Later builds can access the text file as build#1's build artifact (via Web interface, or on disk if running on master).